# Can I use refactoring to exchange the type of a variable for another?

Tags: java, android-studio, refactoring

Android Studio provides powerful refactoring, for example <kbd>Rename</kbd>. I can use it to change the name of variables, fields, parameters, however I cannot seem to find a way to rename a type. For example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(....);
// ........
// A bunch of code using `layout` many times
```

How can I quickly refactor `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and have it be applied to the rest of the code too? And can I do the same thing for fields?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Short Answer

The function you are looking for is <kbd>Type Migration</kbd>!

A <kbd>Type Migration</kbd> can be performed by right clicking on the type of a variable or field and then selecting <kbd>Refactor</kbd> -> <kbd>Type Migration</kbd>. Alternatively you can use these keyboard shortcuts:

- On a Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- On Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Just choose the type you want to migrate to, click refactor and Android Studio starts working its magic!

---

### Long and more detailed Answer

You seem to misunderstand what <kbd>Rename</kbd> actually does.

<kbd>Rename</kbd> can be used to literally rename elements. So you can change the name of a variable, parameter, method or class with it. For example if you have a class named `Foo` and you want to change its name to `Bar` you can do that easily with <kbd>Rename</kbd>.

But you cannot rename `LinearLayout` since it is framework class and those of course cannot be modified. This however shouldn't be a problem at all because you don't actually want to rename `LinearLayout`, do you? What you actually want to do is change the type from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. And there is another very useful refactor feature to do exactly that, it is called <kbd>Type Migration</kbd>.

You can perform a <kbd>Type Migration</kbd> by right clicking on any variable whose type you want to exchange for another and then selecting <kbd>Refactor</kbd> -> <kbd>Type Migration</kbd>. After that a Dialog pops up and you can enter the type you want to migrate to, in your case `RelativeLayout`. Then just click `Refactor` and Android Studio starts working its magic. There may be an additional popup window informing you of all the things in your code which cannot be migrated automatically. Just scan through the list of conflicts and when you are done hit <kbd>Ignore</kbd> and fix those conflicts manually.

Here is an example of <kbd>Type Migration</kbd> at work. I started out with this code:

```
private LinearLayout mLayout;

private void doStuff(ViewGroup container) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(0);

    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    });

    mLayout = layout;
    fooTheBar(layout);   
}

private void fooTheBar(LinearLayout layout) {
    ...
}
```

Now I performed a <kbd>Type Migration</kbd> to `RelativeLayout` on the local variable `layout` in `doStuff()`. The result looks like this:

```
private RelativeLayout mLayout;

private void doStuff(ViewGroup container) {
    // Here is the only conflict which could not be refactored automatically.
    // I had to change the cast to RelativeLayout manually.
    RelativeLayout layout = (LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
    });

    mLayout = layout;
    fooTheBar(layout);
}

private void fooTheBar(RelativeLayout layout) {
    ...
}
```

As you can see <kbd>Type Migration</kbd> did excellent work. The type of the field and even the type of the parameter of `fooTheBar()` was changed to `RelativeLayout`. There was only one conflict. Android Studio couldn't automatically change the type of the cast at the very top of `doStuff()`. I had to fix that manually. As I mentioned earlier I was warned about this conflict while performing the refactoring.

You could of course ask yourself why it could change the type of the field and the parameter automatically but couldn't change the type of a cast, but if you think about it that actually makes a lot of sense:

The part of the code it couldn't migrate automatically was `(LinearLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)`. This method of course looks for a `View` with the id `R.id.linearLayout`. This `View` might be defined in a layout xml or it may be added to the `container` dynamically at runtime but in any case it is not something which can just be refactored automatically without the risk of breaking functionality. It is something only the developer can decide how to handle and that's why you are warned about it.

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't occur to me to `right-click` on type instead of field, that's why `Type Migration` option was unnoticed.

Comment: This works perfectly fine on Java file, however, there is no option `type migration` in Kotlin file. any workaround for Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

For `Type Migration` in Kotlin file:

Say you want to change the input parameter from `String` to `Int` in the following function.

```
fun getValue(key: String){
}
```

1. Place cursor on the type you want to change (String in this case)
2. <kbd>Right click</kbd> > <kbd>Refactor</kbd> > <kbd>Change
   Signature</kbd>. Or use shortcuts below for this step:

   - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
   - Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> (not tested)
3. Completing step 2 will open this window, click on row highlighted with blue:

[image]

4. Replace type with whatever you want and click <kbd>Refactor</kbd>

[image]